# Android TextView in ScrollView - Different color for each new line

Tags: android, text, colors, terminal, scrollview

I am creating sort of terminal-like view, that would display received and transmitted messages over Bluetooth,e.g. received messages in blue, transmitted in red.

So far, i managed to put textView inside scrollView and by using .append() methdod add lines to scroll view.

Layout looks like this:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/disconnectButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Received and sent txt!!!\n"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollTextView"
        android:minLines="11"
        android:maxLines="11"/>
</ScrollView>
```

And code for adding text to scrollView:

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollingView);
scrollTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollTextView);
scrollTextView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); scrollTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.receivedBTColor));
scrollTextView.append("$"+dataInPrint+"\n");
scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

The problem is that each of the lines should be able to be in different colors. setTextColor() method sets color for whole textView, which is totaly not what i want since i need to temporarily save the lines which go upwards until scrollView overflows. I looked at the example of using Spannable class, but it is quite messy.

Could anyone suggest a way to make a scrollable colorful text? Something like this?
[Example from Bluetooth terminal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NZ2C.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a little tricky editing utilizing HTML and Android's `Html.fromHtml()`...

```
String dataInPrint = "" //Whatever the output message is.

String redB = "<font color="red">";
String blueB = "<font color="blue">";
String colorEnd = "</font>";

if(//message is send){
    yourtextview.append(Html.fromHtml(redB + dataInPrint + colorEnd));
}
else{//message is recieve
    yourtextview.append(Html.fromHtml(blueB + dataInPrint + colorEnd));
}
```

Comment: One more thing... When i use Html.fromHtml(), the method seems to exclude "\n" symbol. What i did ,i used basically scrollTextView.append("\n"); on the next line. This works, but maybe there is another way to make use of newline symbol using the same Html.fromHtml() method? Otherwise, huge thanks!!!

Comment: Great! It's a nice little trick to know, you never know when a little HTML is needed in a `TextView`

Comment: Yes, you should be able to utilize HTML's `<br>` tag. Give it a try by just adding `String colorEnd = "</font><br>"`.

Comment: Also you could attempt `yourtextview.append(Html.fromHtml(blueB + dataInPrint + colorEnd) + "\n");`, though I haven't tested

Comment: Utilizing HTML's <br> tag worked! However, the last suggestion didn't work. Text appended newline symbols, but the color didn't change.